# How can I get the size of an application after it was already installed?

Tags: linux, shell, command, size

With the command `whereis` I can get the location of the files but instead summing all the sizes of those files I would like to know if there is simpler way to do this.

Comment: This is going to be distribution-dependent. You can [edit] your post with more details so that people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This answer depends on the distribution you are using. Try to figure out from which package the file is distributed like `xterm` for instance, then get the package size by quering the package repository.

Debian/Ubuntu sample:

```
which xterm
/usr/bin/xterm

dpkg -S /usr/bin/xterm
xterm: /usr/bin/xterm

apt-cache show xterm|grep -i size
Installed-Size: 1659
Size: 664882
```

RedHat/CentOS:

```
which ls
yum whatprovides /usr/bin/ls
coreutils-8.22-11.el7.x86_64 : A set of basic GNU tools commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/ls
.
.
more output
.
.

yum info coreutils-8.22-11.el7.x86_64|grep -i size
Size        : 14 M
```

Solaris 11:

```
which ls
/usr/bin/ls

pkg search /usr/bin/ls
INDEX      ACTION VALUE      PACKAGE
path       file   usr/bin/ls pkg:/system/core-os@0.5.11-0.175.2.6.0.3.2

pkg info pkg:/system/core-os@0.5.11-0.175.2.6.0.3.2 |grep -i size
          Size: 37.58 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ls -lah /path/to/file
```

To see the file size of said file.

```
Examples:
# ls -lah /usr/sbin/httpd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 348K Aug 24 17:53 /usr/sbin/httpd

# ls -la /usr/sbin/httpd 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 355712 Aug 24 17:53 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

*Note:*

Personally, I find it much easier to use the **which** command rather than the **whereis** command.

```
# which httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
```